# How to target higher .net framework from visual studio 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I am a java developer and know very little about .Net. I am working on project which has some screens built using the .Net FrameWork. Recently, client updated to IE11 and now they are facing some .net exception related to Systems.Windows.Form while right clicking on any page.
After some research I realized this is an existing issue with .net 1.1 framework.
Can I point to Systems.Windows.Form.dll of some higher version of .net as I have other versions also installed on my system.

Comment: right click on your project and select properties and change your target framework

Comment: I'm wondering why you have references to System.Windows.Forms in an ASP.Net project? Definitely upgrade your target framework to a recent version and rebuild it, ensuring that any dependent libraries are also upgraded to the same target version.

Comment: What would you do if you had in 2016 to maintain code made for Java 1.2? Seriously - start by upgrading from the extremely bad VS 2003 to a more modern version. Then move the code over. .NET 4.0 - 1.1 is so ancient it is out of extended support.

Comment: @BudaGavril that's completely a wrong answer as it is Visual Studio .NET 2003, which does not even have the concept of target framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Visual Studio version to support Multi-Targeting was VS2008. Before then each version of Visual Studio only supported working with the then current version of the .Net Framework.

VS.Net => .Net 1.0

VS2003 => .Net 1.1

VS2005 => .Net 2.0

So you will have to migrate to a newer version of Visual Studio to resolve the issue.

Normally opening an old solution in a new version of Visual Studio will run an upgrade wizzard that in my experience rarely causes issues. However given how old VS2003 is I have no practical experience with how new versions of Visual Studio will handle it.